# Whose major work was influenced by Descartes?

Tags: descartes

For instance, Newton's ‘Mathematical principles of natural philosophy’ is heavily influenced by Euclid's ‘Elements’. Newton was highly influenced by the Elements. So I would call Newton's book a practical example of Euclid's Elements.

The question is: Where can I find practical example of the Descartes' work?

Is there a such book?

Comment: I had some problems understanding your question. If you feel, I have answered it, is it ok with you if I edit your question to ask for...[harrumph] my answer more directly?

Comment: yes, it's indeed OK. Your answer was helpful thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: But rewritten in these terms,the question is quite trivial : all Western Philosophy post-Descartes was influenced by Descartes' thought, exactly as all mathematics  (pure and applied) was heavily influenced by Euclid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I tried to improve the formulation of the question. If you feel I've gone too far, please do re-edit it. I didn't want to give an unsuitable answer and than rewrite the question until it fits the answer ...!

Comment: @Einer - The first versione alluded to a purported influence of D's [rules of method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_on_the_Method), with regard - I think - to the [Regulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_for_the_Direction_of_the_Mind). If so, the question is much more "restricted" in scope comapred to the enormous influence of D's thought on modern western philosophy (and - partially - science).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA As I said: I don't cling to the current formulation! But as taeyun seemed to be happy with my answer I thought I could use that as an triangulation-point for my edit. If you think it's too much, please do roll back!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think all of Western religion, science, philosophy, and psychology since...would be too conservative of an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's hard to name a single book since Descartes heavily impacted all of western philosophy. A major work heavily influenced by Descartes would be [The Monadology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadology) by Gottfried Leibniz. But there were a lot of philosophers inspired by Descartes - be it rejecting his ideas or approving of them. To drop some famous names: Spinoza, Pascal, Locke, Fichte or Husserl. Given that it is really hard to point out one the one single book analogous to Newtons 'Principia'

Answer (score 2):

Einer's answer is absolutely correct, but since your question specifically mentions "practical" impact, it's worth additionally mentioning that Descartes' work in mathematics was also hugely influential, since he invented Cartesian coordinates, without which you cannot do analytic geometry, calculus or nearly any other modern mathematical task.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a kind of "practical work" influenced by Cartesian philosophy is the [Port Royal Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port-Royal_Logic), which was written by Arnauld and Nicole, and Pascal may have contributed as well.